# Exponential fitting in R with fixed minimal value

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, exponential-smoothing

I need approximate datapoints by exponential function with some type of lower limit (variable "y" is price in time and I need fixed minimal value, so asymptote of exponential function cant be at 0). I found this article https://rpubs.com/mengxu/exponential-model but does not help solve my problem. How can I solve it? Thanks

My problem:

```
y <- c(26973, 24907, 22999, 21236, 19609, 18107, 16720, 15439, 14256, 13163, 
           12155, 11224, 10364,  9570,  8360)

x <- c(1:15)
train <- data.frame(x, y)
colnames(train) <- c("x", "y")

plot(x,y, ylim = c(0, 30000), col = "blue", lwd = 2)
abline(5000, 0, col = "red")

#Then, I fit exponential curve on my datapoints

fit_exp <- lm(log(y) ~ x, data = train)
pred <- exp(fit_exp$coefficients\[1\] + fit_exp$coefficients\[2\]*train$x)
plot(x,y, ylim = c(0, 30000), col = "blue", lwd = 2)
points(train$x, pred, type = "l", col = "black")

#prediction for expanded x
x_exp <- c(1:60)
pred_exp <- exp(fit_exp$coefficients\[1\] + fit_exp$coefficients\[2\]*x_exp)

plot(x_exp, pred_exp, type = "b", col = "blue", lwd = 2)
abline(5000, 0, col = "red")
```

[image: Red Line show min value]

Approach by https://rpubs.com/mengxu/exponential-model:

```
theta.0 <- 5000 
model.0 <- lm(log(y - theta.0) ~ x, data = train)  
alpha.0 <- exp(coef(model.0)[1])
beta.0 <- coef(model.0)[2]

start <- list(alpha = alpha.0, beta = beta.0, theta = theta.0)
print(start)
model <- nls(y ~ alpha * exp(beta * x) + theta , data = train, start = start)

plot(train$x, train$y)
lines(train$x, predict(model, list(x = train$x)), col = 'skyblue', lwd = 3)


x_exp <- c(1:60)
pred_model <- coef(model)[1] * exp(coef(model)[2] * x_exp) + coef(model)[3]

plot(x_exp, pred_model, type = "b", col = "blue", lwd = 2)
abline(5000, 0, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: My first reaction to this was far too much R code to wade through, but a more benign reaction is just to discuss how far the data support a non-zero asymptote.

Comment: The idea is: I have prices for 15 years aproximate by exponential function. So if I need price at year 30 then calculate my exp function with x = 30... Thats clear. But I know from year 25 to n the price must by some fixed value (residual value). And thats it, when I calculate mi exp function for x = 30 then result is smaller than residual value. So I need fix this

Comment: Indeed. I think your goal is easy to understand but hard to achieve.

Comment: Have you any idea how to do that? Maybe I could try some kind of two stage regression. At first at my dataset (x = 1:15). Second train in spread dataset (x = 1:100) where all values smaller than scrap val = scrap val...? What you mean?

Comment: Again, it seems that you don’t have data to test your ideas about what happen.

Answer (score 2):

Your data seem at odds with your expectations. I get this from a model fitted by nonlinear least squares in Stata (hoping that the syntax is fairly transparent):

```
. nl (y = {a=5000} + {b=30000} * exp(-{k}*x))

Iteration 0:  residual SS =  3.87e+08
Iteration 1:  residual SS =  6.13e+07
Iteration 2:  residual SS =  3.17e+07
Iteration 3:  residual SS =  142078.7
Iteration 4:  residual SS =  139863.6
Iteration 5:  residual SS =  139858.4
Iteration 6:  residual SS =  139858.4
Iteration 7:  residual SS =  139858.4


      Source |      SS            df       MS
-------------+----------------------------------    Number of obs =         15
       Model |  4.727e+08          2   236371094    R-squared     =     0.9997
    Residual |  139858.39         12  11654.8657    Adj R-squared =     0.9997
-------------+----------------------------------    Root MSE      =   107.9577
       Total |  4.729e+08         14    33777289    Res. dev.     =   179.6732

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          /a |   -1296.85   625.1335    -2.07   0.060    -2658.899    65.19892
          /b |   30397.15   549.1044    55.36   0.000     29200.75    31593.55
          /k |   .0744545   .0026653    27.93   0.000     .0686472    .0802617
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: Parameter a is used as a constant term during estimation.
```

Nonlinear least squares in my experience needs good initial guesses to work well. Here there is good convergence to a negative asymptote, not at all what you want or expect. I can't be confident without a great deal of experiment that different guesses would lead to the same answer.

Indeed, a plain regression of log $y$ on $x$ also fits very well, implying an asymptote of zero for $y$.

Executive summary: I think your data don't extend far enough in $x$ to determine limiting behaviour at all well. Variations on technique won't solve this.